# Fast algorithm to encode (sub)sets to unique numbers

Tags: algorithm, mapping, set

So, I have the situation that I wish to map the powerset of a set to a unique number (index) for each of its elements, and then associate this number to a non-unique value in a map or a list. I want this in order to not have to store all the subsets explicitly, but only the unique number associated with them. If a linear-time (preferably, but I suppose I can afford a higher degree polynomial if it is necessary) algorithm exists that uniquely produces a number from the elements of the subsets, that would be great to have. From intuition, I think such an algorithm could exist, using some summing or convolution functions on the elements of the subset.

In formal terms, I have a universe `U = {1,2,3,...,n}` of which I need all subsets. There are `2^n` such subsets. I have a function `f` mapping from a subset `X` to a number `y`, ie `f(X)=y`. `y` is a non-unique number.

Now, I need in my program to be able to move from one subsets `X` value to another subsets `Y` value, where `Y = X - {k}` for some `k ϵ X`. So if there was an algorithm where I could calculate the unique identifier for `Y` from its elements, then I only need to remove `k` and use the (remaining) elements of `X` to find it, instead of searching through a list of stored subsets, which requires searching, comparing AND the memory cost of storing each subset.

So, does anyone know if such an algorithm exists?

Comment: Can you make your question clear? I don't under your last paragraph

Comment: I appreciate your attempt to make the question clear.but unfortunately it's still out of grasp.Can you explain it with an example?The last para example is sort of difficult to understand

Comment: The standard approach is to use a binary number to represent sets.  For example the binary number 00001011 would represent the set that contains the 1st, 2nd, and 4th elements from U.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition, any unique identifier would need as many bits as there are elements in your set `U`.  So if the elements in `U` are fixed and ordered, you could easily compute a bit vector from the elements of any subset `Y` (only the bits corresponding to elements in the set `Y` are set) and covert it to a number.  Of course, depending on the maximal size of `U`, you might need some infinite-precision data type.

Comment: This looks like a smart approach. And I dont need to sort the subsets. Each element e would be converted to 2^e and then all summed up.

Answer (score 0):

Power sets might be the key to solving your issue. See [here](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set#Representing_subsets_as_functions) some modification might be necessary tu support 2^n